# sumar todos los valores de una columna - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Buen día, tengo un tabla "material-table.com" en `reactjs` y necesito que todos  los valores de la columna de `valor_t2` se sumen y me muestre el resultado al final de la tabla.

Lo he intentado agregando un `renderSummaryRow` pero no me muestra nada, envio una captura de pantalla de como quiero que quede y también envio mi código de lo que he intentado tratando de obtener el resultado que necesito.

Intente implementar `renderSummaryRow` que fue lo que encontré pero no he tenido éxito.

Como quiero que quede:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código:

```javascript
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { AddBox, ArrowDownward } from "@material-ui/icons";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

import axios from 'axios';

function Moneda() {
    const baseUrlAd = "https://miweb.com"
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const peticionGet = async () => {
        await axios.get(baseUrlAd)
            .then(response => {
                setData(response.data);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })

    }
    peticionGet();
    const columnas = [
        {
            title: "ID",
            field: "id",
          
        {
            title: 'Age',
            field: 'valor_t2',

        },


    ];

    return (
        <div id="content" class="app-content">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <MaterialTable
                    columns={columnas}
                    data={data}
                    title={ }
                    backIconButtonText='Página anterior'
                    pagination
                    fixedHeader
                    /* lo que he intentado pero no me muestra nada*/
                    renderSummaryRow={({ column, data }) =>
                        column.field === "valor_t2"
                            ? {
                                value: data.reduce((agg, row) => agg + Number(row.valor_t2), 0),
                                style: { background: "red" },
                            }
                            : undefined
                    }
                    actions={[

                    ]}
                    options={{
                        actionsColumnIndex: -1,
                        actionsCellStyle: {
                        },
                        localization={{
        header:{
                    actions: 'ACCIONES'
      },
                body:{
                    emptyDataSourceMessage:'No hay registros que mostrar',
       },
       
    }}
    />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
    }

export default Moneda
```

//lo que carga en variable get
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//lo que me carga actualmente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: revisa la comparación no es la correcta   'valor_t' === "valor_t2"

Comment: intente con "==", tambien "=" y no me carga nada

Comment: const columnas =[
    {
      title:"ID",
      field: "id",
      
    {
      title:'Age',
      field: 'valor_t2', << colocando asi  
     
    },
  ];

Comment: no entiendo como seria, me puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: o lo puedes añadir al codigo

Comment: en el array  columnas  que usted coloco  la propiedad field : 'valor_t'  la puedes cambiar  a  field : 'valor_t2'

Comment: Ya corregí pero el pero el problema persiste

Comment: Ya corregí pero el  problema persiste, es como si no me reconociera renderSummaryRow

Comment: comprobaste la funcion reducer  si la data que viene del state es la correcta a sumar

Comment: lo raro es que ni siquiera me carga la fila donde debe aparecer el resultado se la Suma

Comment: Te voy a dejar este ejemplo que te puede servir  https://material-table-core.com/demos/Summaryrow/basic/

Comment: Ese es el ejemplo que estoy tratando de seguir pero al adaptarlo a mi código no me funciona es como si no reconociera renderSummaryRow, solo me carga la tabla

Comment: puede hacer un screenshot de lo obtiene el path  "https://miweb.com" lo que guarda en el state

Comment: ya agregue un "screenshot"

Comment: en el reducer  en la parametro row.valor_t2 cambialo a un  Number(row.valor_t2)   para que sume , si no funciona pasame el codigo en un repositorio

Comment: no me carga la suma, subio un pantallazo de lo que me aparece

Comment: encontre el problema pero no la solucion, lo que pasa es que mis datos cargan desde un base de datos y la funcion renderSummaryRow no alcanza a realizar la suma ya que los datos se demoran un poco en cargar, como hago para agregar un boton o retrasar la carga de renderSummaryRow  para posteriormente que cargue los datos puedan generar la suma

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto sea tu respuesta, se crea un useEffect para enviar la información al state luego se creo una  funcion llamada Nuevo lo cual puede crear un componente aparte

```
tuve que agregar al id 
    components={{
              Row: (props) => <MTableBodyRow id={props.index} {...props} />
            }}
```

le voy a dejar el link https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-cori-umhck1?file=/src/App.js:0-2088

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

```
import axios from "axios";

import MaterialTable, { MTableBodyRow } from "@material-table/core";

function App() {
  //const baseUrlAd = `https://parqueoenvia.co/apiParqueoenvia/operadores/arqueo_cargar.php?id_operador=${global.id}`;
  const [dataNew, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const peticionGet = async () => {
      await axios
        .get(
          `https://parqueoenvia.co/apiParqueoenvia/operadores/arqueo_cargar.php?id_operador=59`
        )
        .then(({ data }) => {
          const d = data.map((d, i) => ({
            id: i + 1,
            date: d.fecha_hora,
            age: Number(d.valor_t2)
          }));

          setData(d);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
    peticionGet();
  }, [setData]);

  const Nuevo = ({ data }) => {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: "ID",
        field: "id"
      },
      {
        title: "Date",
        field: "date"
      },

      {
        title: "Age",
        field: "age",
        type: "numeric"
      }
    ];

    return (
      <MaterialTable
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        components={{
          Row: (props) => <MTableBodyRow id={props.index} {...props} />
        }}
        renderSummaryRow={({ column, data }) =>
          column.field === "age"
            ? {
                value: data.reduce((agg, row) => agg + row.age, 0),
                style: { background: "red" }
              }
            : undefined
        }
        pagination
        fixedHeader
        actions={[]}
        options={{
          actionsColumnIndex: -1,
          actionsCellStyle: {},

          body: {
            emptyDataSourceMessage: "No hay registros que mostrar"
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <div id="content" className="app-content">
      <div className="panel-body">
        <Nuevo data={dataNew} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que renderSummaryRow solo carga una vez así como está , así le agregué useEffect a la baseURL eso mantiene actualizado el cargue de la información pero lo que necesito es que renderSummaryRow también se este actualizando constantemente

Comment: tiene link repositorio para revisarlo

Comment: te envio el link https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-rumple-x6fzwi?file=/src/App.js:0-1837